# What is the time complexity and space complexity of a recursive algorithm with the || operator?

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have an algorithm that checks whether or not a game row can be solved. The game row is an array of positive integers, where the last element is 0. The game marker starts at index 0 and moves along the array the number of steps indicated by the integer it is positioned at.

For example, [1, 1, 0] returns true, while [1, 2, 0] returns false.
The marker can also move left or right in order to solve the game.
That is, [3, 3, 2, 2, 0] is solvable.

```
Algorithm recursiveSolvable(gameArray, index)
     if index = gameArray.length - 1     // the last element has been reached
          return true
     if index < 0 || index >= gameArray.length || arrayList.contains(index)
          return false
     arrayList.add(index)     // store visited indices to avoid infinite loop
     else
          // move towards the goal (last element) if possible
          // otherwise, trace back steps to find another way
          return recursiveSolvable(gameArray, index + gameArray[index])
                 || recursiveSolvable(gameArray, index - gameArray[index])
```

I have tried with a few examples of game rows and calculated the time complexity in the worst case:

```
[2, 0] has 2 recursive calls where the first one returns false, and the second one as well
[1, 1, 2, 0] has 5:
     go right || go left - false
        |
     go right || go left - false 
        |
     go right || go left - false (because index 0 has been visited)
        |
      false (then go left)
```

Other cases gave me numbers that I couldn't find the relation with the input size, but when I run the program with input size n = 100, the output is shown instantly, so I assume the time complexity is not O(2^n) (like binary recursion). I am more leaning towards O(n)...

As for the space complexity, I have no idea how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The run time is indeed more like O(n). This is because each index position is investigated only once (due to the test with the `arrayList`).

The exact bound depends also on the data structure used for `arrayList`. Is it really a `List` or a `HashSet`?

The space complexity is O(n) for the same reason. There can only be one incarnation of the recursive method for each index position.